# What is the preferred way to take the modulus by a power of 2 of an int in Python

Tags: python, integer, twos-complement

Imagine that you have some counter or other data element that needs to be stored in a field of a binary protocol. The field naturally has some fixed number *n* of bits and the protocol specifies that you should store the *n* least significant bits of the counter, so that it wraps around when it is too large. One possible way to implement that is actually taking the modulus by a power of two:

```
field_value = counter % 2 ** n
```

But this certainly isn't the most efficient way and maybe not even the easiest to understand, taking into account that the specification is talking about the *least significant bits* and does not mention a modulus operation. Thus, investigating alternatives is appropriate. Some examples are:

```
field_value = counter % (1 << n)
field_value = counter & (1 << n) - 1
field_value = counter & ~(-1 << 8)
```

What is the way preferred by experienced Python programmers to implement such a requirement trying to maximize code clarity without sacrificing too much performance?

There is of course no right or wrong answer to this question, so I would like to use this question to collect all the reasonable implementations of this seemingly trivial requirement. An answer should list the alternatives and shortly describe in what circumstance what alternative would preferably be used.

Comment: What version of Python is this?

Comment: _"the specification is talking about the least significant bits and does not mention a modulus operation."_ True, but I suspect it also does not mention `<<` or `&` or `~`, so it's no worse than any of your other examples in that respect.

Comment: Make it easy to understand and easy to read. Forget performance.  Optimize later with a help of a Profiler.

Comment: Only a profiler can tell you what is faster. If the python interpreter is worth anything at all it will know about these kind of transformations and should apply them for you anyway.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Solutions should preferably work in version 2.7 as well as 3.0 and onwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit shifting and bitwise operations are more readable in your case. Because it simply tells the reader, you are doing bitwise operations here. If you use numeric operation, the reader may not be able to understand what does it mean by moduloing that number.

Talking about performance, actually you don't have to worry too much about this in Python. Because operation to Python object itself is expensive enough, by either doing it in numeric operations or bitwise operations, it simply doesn't matter. Here I explain it in a visual way

```
<-------------- Python object operation cost --------------><- bit op ->
<-------------- Python object operation cost --------------><----- num op ----->
```

This is just a simple rough idea of what it costs to perform a simplest bit operation or number operation. As you can see Python object operation cost takes the majority, so it doesn't matter you use bitwise or numeric, the difference is too small can be ignored.

If you really need performance, you have to process massive amount of data, you should consider

1. Write the logic in C/C++ module for Python, you can use library like [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/)
2. Use third party library for mass number processing such as [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)

Comment: Performance is certainly not an issue with any of the solutions I provided. In my case, the execution of the Python application looks something like this: `------------------------------------------------------------X---------------------------------`, where `X` is the part where one or two such operations are performed. I wanted to discourage answers where e.g. a new number type was introduced, overloading the `+` operator, that did the modulo operation internally.

Answer (score 1):

you should simply throw away the top bits.

```
#field_value = counter & (1 << n) - 1
field_value = counter & ALLOWED_BIT_WIDTH
```

If this was implemented in an embedded device, the registers used could be the limiting factor. In my experience this is way it is normally done.

The "limitation" in the protocol is a way of constraining the overhead bandwidth needed by the protocol.

Comment: This … does not really address my question. That I have to do it and that there's some reason that the protocol requires me to do it is part of the premises. Here, I'm trying to look at different possible ways of actually doing it.

Comment: Yes I agree.  And I gave you the way I think it is done commonly in embedded devices.

Answer (score 1):

It will be dependent on the python implementation probably, but in CPython 2.6, it looks like this:

```
In [1]: counter = 0xfedcba9876543210
In [10]: %timeit counter % 2**15
1000000 loops, best of 3: 304 ns per loop

In [11]: %timeit counter % (1<<15)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 302 ns per loop

In [12]: %timeit counter & ((1<<15)-1)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 104 ns per loop

In [13]: %timeit counter & ~(1<<15)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 170 ns per loop
```

In this case, `counter & ((1<<15)-1)` is the clear winner. Interesting is that `2**15` and `1<<15` take the same amount of time (more or less); I am guessing Python internally optimizes this case and 2**15 -> 1<<15 anyways.

I once wrote a class that lets you just do this:

```
 bc = BitSliceLong(counter)
 bc = bc[15:0]
```

derived from long, but it's a more general implementation (lets you take any range of the bits, not just x:0) and the extra overhead for that makes it slower by an order of magnitude, even though it's using the same method inside.

Edit: BTW, precalculating the values doesn't appear to provide any benefit - the dominant factor here is not the actual math operation. If we do

```
cx_mask = 2**15
counter % cx_mask
```

the time is the same as when it had to calculate 2**15. This was also true for our 'best case' - precalculating ((1<<15)-1) has no benefit.

Also, in the previous case, I used a large number that is implemented as a `long` in python. This is not really a native type - it supports arbitrary length numbers, and so needs to handle nearly anything, so implementing operations is not just a single ALU call - it involves a series of bit-shifting and arithmetic operations.

If you can keep the counter below `sys.maxint`, you'll be using `int` types instead, and they both appear to be faster & also more dominated by actual math code:

```
In [55]: %timeit x % (1<<15)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 53.6 ns per loop

In [56]: %timeit x & ((1<<15)-1)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 49.2 ns per loop

In [57]: %timeit x % (2**15)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 53.9 ns per loop
```

These are all about the same, so it doesn't matter which one you use here really. (mod slightly slower, but within random variation). It makes sense for div/mod to be an expensive operation on very large numbers, with a more complex algorithm, while for 'small' ints it can be done in hardware.